# How do I export a Visual studio Visual basic.net project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have created a project in VB.net inside of Visual studio. I want to export the entire project to my USB stick so that I can send it to a friend who might be able to help me on my project - but from their separate computer.

I tried exporting the project a few times yesterday to things such as zipped folders or e-mail files but everytime I opened them up it said there was something missing, so I want to try sending it to my friend via a USB stick instead.

Is it possible to export my file to a USB stick so that they can edit it? How do I do this?

Comment: Where ever the project is stored, just zip all that into a new zip file; nothing else should matter. `everytime I opened them up it said there was something missing`, do you think *its not important to post this information* so we can better help you?

Comment: Sorry! It says the  VB.proj file is missing

Comment: `It says the VB.proj file is missing`, that's a pretty obvious error. If you just take the main folder and zip it up, you will have everything you need; don't cherry pick files...

Answer (score 1):

You just copy the whole folder that the solution (.sln) is in including all files and subfolders. There is no behind-the-scenes-magic, it's just the files in that folder. You can zip it if you feel that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

So I just moved the entire folder to the USB without zipping it and it prompts me to open a valid file location but all I have to do is go to the right menu and click on he sln.file and it works fine. My friend should be able to help now - thanks for the help everyone above